# Discrepancy $δ$ in the Berlekamp-Massey Algorithm

Tags: stream-cipher, finite-field, lfsr

I have a question regarding to the [Berlekamp–Massey algorithm](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=Berlekamp-Massey_algorithm). Can someone guide me to understand the idea/intuition of this algorithm?

According to the explanation in [Wikepedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm), in each iteration, the algorithm is trying to calculate the discrepancy $δ$.

If $δ≠0$, the algorithm will update the error locator polynomial using an update polynomial $B(x)$. However, at this point, I know that the resulted error locator polynomial will make the $δ$ in current iteration become zero. But, how about all the $δ$ in previous iterations? It is very hard to visualize that the algorithm actually makes all previous $δ=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, BMA is a recursive algorithm and the discrepancy $$d_{n+1}=\hat{s}_{n+1}-s_{n+1}$$is the *difference* between

- What the current polynomial $C^{\{n\}}$ determined by BMA based on the sequence $(s_0,\cdots,s_n)$ predicts as the next symbol $\hat{s}_{n+1}$, and
- The actual symbol $s_{n+1}$.

This is what is used to update the polynomial if necessary. By induction, all discrepancies are then zero.

Comment: But I couldn't visualize from the case that adding the updated polynomial, $B(x)$ can actually make the new error-locator polynomial generate all the previous $s_0,\cdots,s_{n-1}$ with 0 discrepancies. Do you mind giving me a small proof of showing it is true?

Comment: The equation that bother me is $C(x) <- C(X) + (d/b)(x^m)B(X)$  (note: the notation is from the Wikipedia). I know that after this modification, the $C(X)$ will generate the sequence $s_n$ with 0 discrepancy. But, how can the algorithm make sure that it can still generate all previous sequence $s_0,\cdots,s_{n-1}$ with 0 discrepancies?

Comment: Don't use wikipedia as an authoritative source. It's not easy to determine where they err, if they do. The proof goes by induction but it is a bit delicate, I don't have time to describe it now. Blahut's book *Fast Algorithms for Signal Processing* has a good description, in section 7.4. The book is possible to find online.

Comment: Thank you for recommending the book. It's very usefull!! I got it now!

Answer (score 1):

The Berlekamp-Massey algorithm is a procedure for LFSR *synthesis*; it. finds the *shortest* LFSR that will produce the given sequence $s_0, s_1, s_2, \cdots$.  The algorithm is *iterative* (not recursive since it doesn't call itself) in that it examines the sequence one symbol at a time until it has processed the entire given sequence. At the end of the $i$-th iteration, the algorithm has examined $s_0, s_1, \cdots, s_{i-1}$ (examination of $s_i, s_{i+1}, \cdots$ is yet to come) and has synthesized the *shortest* LFSR  that will generate $s_0, s_1, \cdots, s_{i-1}$. Then, at the beginning of the $(i+1)$-th iteration, the algorithm determines whether $s_i$ will be generated by the LFSR it has just found by computing what the *next* output $\hat{s}_i$ would be from the just-synthesized LFSR, and comparing it to what we *want* the LFSR to generate, namely, the *given* $s_i$.  The difference is called the *discrepancy* $\delta_i$ and if $\delta_i$ happens to be nonzero, the *previously*-synthesized LFSR is *updated* so that the updated LFSR will compute $s_0, s_1, \cdots, s_{i-1}, {\mathbf s_i}$ (emphasis added). This update might increase the LFSR length and also change the feedback taps, or just change the feedback taps. It can be proven that if an iteration resulted in an increase in LFSR length and changing the taps, then on the very next iteration, only the feedback taps might change; the LFSR cannot increase in length.

In short, there is no need to worry about what happens to previous discrepancies; the current LFSR is *guaranteed to generate all of the sequence examined thus far* without any discrepancies creeping in during the generation process.